# Possibility to manipulate TLS1.2 communication within a Jetty environment

Tags: ssl, networking, jetty

I have a strange question and spent more than a week to find a solution.

Does anybody know a possibility how I can adapt the sources from my embedded Jetty server in a way that I can manipulate the whole communication? I'm especially interested in manipulating the responses used for the TLS v1.2 handshake and the communication with this protocol at any time. I need this for writing a simulation of a system - this system shall be tested in many ways including the described use case.

I already created an example which uses a created certificate to start a secured webservice. It is also possible for the web browser to connect to the web service by using HTTPS - so far so good.

I set a breakpoint within my HttpServlet class and I reach this breakpoint. The test answer is generated and the answer is sent back (The method `write()` within the class `Iso88591Http` is used) where I can find the TLS v1.2 encryption?

I hope I explained the problem in a good way and someone has an idea.

Comment: You can't even do that in Java, let alone Jetty, unless you write your own SSL provider.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you are missing the [`SecureRequestCustomizer`](https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/blob/jetty-9.3.1.v20150714/jetty-server/src/main/java/org/eclipse/jetty/server/SecureRequestCustomizer.java#L139-L144) in your environment.

That will inject the relevant pieces from the established SSLSesssion into the request attributes.

This Customizer is added in the typical way, via the `HttpConfiguration.addCustomizer()` method.

See full fledged example on the [embedded-jetty-cookbook github repository](https://github.com/jetty-project/embedded-jetty-cookbook).  The [`ServerConnectorHttps` example](https://github.com/jetty-project/embedded-jetty-cookbook/blob/master/src/main/java/org/eclipse/jetty/cookbook/ServerConnectorHttps.java) has the setup you are looking for.

Comment: Thank you very much! I will try this :)
Am I allowed to adapt and manipulate the "relevant pieces" from the established SSLSession with this? If not do you have a clue what to do?

Comment: You can't change anything with the TLS layer at that point.  The connection is already established, everything you see in the SSLSession is essentially immutable at that point.  What you seem to be asking about would require a custom SSL layer in Java.  If you go down this path, be careful of differences in Linux vs WIndows vs OSX.

Comment: Or are you asking about how to configure the negotiation of ciphers and protocols during the TLS connection?  If so, that's just a configuration, not code.

Comment: Hi, no the question was regarding the manipulation of the SSL data itself. I guess to achieve this goal I have to convince Jetty to use an adapted custom TSL layer as you suggested. I had already a look how to do this and I belive it is a good idea to use CyaSSL Java SSL provider.